Is there a software or ML Model than can detect the presence of lyrics in songs?
I need to build a dataset for a project. For this I need some software than can detect when lyrics (human speech) appear in songs. Already tried WebRTC VAD and Silero but they really do not play well with music (lots of false positives and false negatives). So is there anything I can use for this?
